# how to bold date from database in monthcalendar c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have date in my SQL Server database and I want bold this date into month calendar. I do this in C# and Windows Forms.

I have in table terminr date czwartek, 10 listopada 2022 and I need to bold this in month calendar. Can someone help me?

Comment: Engleski 0 bodova

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that you already got the date from your database into a `DateTime` object named `date` and your `DatePicker` object in `datePiker`.

```cs
datePicker.SelectedDate = date;
```

The Date is then selected and bolt by default.